# what does so-meul mean??? 참 진영이는 봐도 봐도 얼굴이 소멸 직전이네

Tags: vocabulary

BoA: 참 진영이는 봐도 봐도 얼굴이 소멸 직전이네

she said it to a good-looking idol trainee. Is it just the literal meaning or is there something more??

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify it. Where did you see this phrase? What is the context? Did you check a dictionary?

Comment: https://dict.naver.com/search.nhn?dicQuery=%EC%86%8C%EB%A9%B8&query=%EC%86%8C%EB%A9%B8&target=dic&ie=utf8&query_utf=&isOnlyViewEE=

Answer (score 5):

As per the dictionary definition, 소멸(消滅) is extinction; 소멸 직전이다 means 'about to become extinct'.

This is actually a compliment - Koreans find small faces attractive; a face that is 'about to go extinct' is understood to be pleasingly small.

Comment: thanks. i found an instagram hashtag for it! though I will say the people tagged with the urjjang hashtag are better-looking...